# Sketch: how to scroll to selected element

Tags: sketch-app

I have a large page of symbols, while creating them, I didn't do a good job of keep them aligned nicely, and as you know by default, Sketch appends the new symbol to the right of the rightmost symbol that is already created. This is why I ended up having a super long/wide page of symbols where only one or two symbols are shown on the visible window area.

I wonder if there is any way to **Search** , **select** and then **go to** the selected symbol on the page. An example would be when you search for text in a browser window, the window moves as you search for **next occurrence**.

Here is a screenshot that reflects my use case: I searched for **input**, and I have the symbols filtered. Now I just hope I could click one of them and **go to** where it is on the page/canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to [center the selected layer](https://sketchapp.com/docs/shortcuts/#zoom-and-focus) in the Canvas.

Alternatively you can use the the menu: `View`>`Center Selection`.

Comment: Also useful: `View → Layer List → Collapse All Groups`
and `Zoom: Selection`

Comment: It's actually View -> Sidebar -> Collapse All Groups now. Heaven forbid they put this in the GUI in the sidebar.